# SQL Server unpivot for report

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I'm trying to re-arrange some data for a report-

I've got one table with a list of locations:

```
| LocationID | LocationName |
```

and another with:

```
 | LocationID | OrderNum | Count |
```

I'm trying to make a select statement that returns:

```
 | OrderNum | LocationName1 | LocationName2 | LocationName3 |...

   orderNum1  |count1           |count1           |count1           |...
   orderNum2  |count2           |count2           |count2           |...
```

Basically a count or orders by order number, for each location... any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This looks more like a `PIVOT` than an `UNPIVOT` to me

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
create table ##Locations  (LocationID int , LocationName varchar(15))
create table ##OrderNums  (LocationID int , OrderNum  varchar(15), _count  int )


insert ##Locations values (1,'LocationName1'),(2,'LocationName2'),(3,'LocationName3'),(4,'LocationName4')
insert ##OrderNums values (1,'orderNum1',2),(2,'orderNum1',3),(4,'orderNum1',5),
(3,'orderNum2',2),(4,'orderNum2',3),(4,'orderNum3',5),(4,'orderNum2',5)


declare @sql nvarchar(max) =''
declare @columns nvarchar(max) =''
Select @columns = @columns + N'[' + LocationName + N'],' from ##Locations

SET  @sql = N'select OrderNum,' +  Left(@columns, Len(@columns) - 1) + N' from (
select o.OrderNum, l.LocationName,   _count  from ##OrderNums o inner join ##Locations l on o.LocationID = l.LocationID
 ) as St pivot ( sum(_count) for LocationName in ( ' +  Left(@columns, Len(@columns) - 1) + N') ) pvt'


exec sp_executesql @sql

OrderNum        LocationName1 LocationName2 LocationName3 LocationName4
--------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
orderNum1       2             3             NULL          5
orderNum2       NULL          NULL          2             8
orderNum3       NULL          NULL          NULL          5
```